# How do I add new strings to iOS app for localization?

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

I have localized my app and set up the Localization.string file.

Now that I want to add new strings, how do I make it so the corresponding files get the new strings automatically?  Or do I have to manually add them?

Just not sure how I should organize my translators to be able to see that there are new strings to translate without having to just keep track of it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an automatic way to manage them.

What we do is add a "//New" or "//Changed" to the end the english resource string, and our translators remove it when they add the other umpteen versions.

Answer (score 0):

We actually put a \ tag with the date the item was added in order to let the translators know what is new and when it was added.

Another thing that we do is leverage a tool which auto translates our English localizable.strings files into target languages using Google's api service.  While Google's translations aren't perfect, they are a great start for our translators.  This really jumpstarted our translation process.  [Link to Apple Store app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/generate-localizable-strings/id572287184?ls=1&mt=12).

Comment: Thanks a lot - yeah I was sort of trying to avoid using Google translate but my translators are a bit unresponsive so I may need to just get it started that way.  Appreciate it.  Out of curiosity, what's your app?